# Wordpress: How to build a link with php-function call?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a logout link to my wordpress page.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('https://www.mywebsite.de/') ?>">Logout</a>
```

The link is visible on the page but when i click it it redirects me to

```
https://www.mywebsite.de/%3C?php%20echo%20wp_logout_url(%27https://www.mywebsite.de/%27)%20?%3E
```

which of course result in a 404. Obviously the php code is not executed. What am i doing wrong? How can i build the link dynamically?

**EDIT:**

I want to place this link via wordpress dashboard to the navigation menu (Appearance -> Menus -> Costum Links). For a first try i just added the link to my front page (Pages -> All Pages -> Choose Front Page --> added link in editor to page content). 
In booth cases the php code is not executed but added to the link which results of course in a broken link (404).

The control characters like "<" get substituded. The whitespaces too. Maybe it is a character encoding problem?

Comment: Try this `<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>`

Comment: Are you wanting to redirect to a different site? If so see this link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url part titled Logout and Redirect to Another Site

Comment: No it is the same site. The problem is that the php is not executed. In the link you can see the php code which should be transformed in a valid logout link.

Comment: Is this in your header.php file? I dont see why php wouldn't execute one place and not another. Do you have debugging turned on in the wp_config.php? Can you edit your post to include more code around it?

Comment: @Radmation Please see my edit. I tried to integrate the link over the wordpress dashboard. Maybe this is causing problems? I never debugged wordpress before. Would it help you to understand the problem? Which infos would you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that is not possible to execute php code in wordpress editor (which is a good thing due to security reasons). 
So i found another way: I created a shortcode for generating my dynamic link/url. With the plugin 'Shortcodes in Menus' everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/

Comment: That is exactly what i did. Problem is not the php function i guess. Problem seems to be that the php code is never executed but the code is treated like part of the url (as you can see when you take a look at the redirected url).

Comment: You want to insert php code in wordpress editor. You can do this by using this plugin but use it at your own risk https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

Comment: Since there will always be a security risk. I personally don't suggest to write php code in the editor.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Plugin works well but the risk is of course a problem.